# Android having problems adding buttons dynamically

Tags: java, android, dynamic

So, I'm trying to add buttons to a scrollview for each item in an arraylist. But while the program runs just fine, buttons don't seem to show up. Can someone tell me where I might be doing things wrong, or what I might be missing?

Here's the code where I try to add the buttons:

```
public void setScreen(){

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.invScr);
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<ItemBase>> items = hero.getStuff();
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

    for (Entry<String, ArrayList<ItemBase>> entry : items.entrySet()){
         String key = entry.getKey();
         ArrayList<ItemBase> value = entry.getValue();

         for (ItemBase item: value){
             LayoutParams rpram = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             bt.add(new Button(this));
             bt.get(i).setText(key);
             bt.get(i).setLayoutParams(rpram);
             layout.addView(bt.get(i));
             invn.add(item);
             bt.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    j = i;

                }
            });
             i++;
         }
    }
    rl.addView(sv);
    sv.addView(layout);

}
```

Here's some other code I have earlier

```
ArrayList<ItemBase> invn = new ArrayList<ItemBase>();
ArrayList<Button> bt = new ArrayList<Button>();
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
```

And here's the xml file for the layout if it's relevant

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/invScr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toCharacter"
        android:text="Back" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoDis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/eatbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="useItem"
        android:text="Use" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is `bt`? Looks like a layout problem so far.

Comment: I've added where I initialized bt and all that.

Comment: can you share your layout xml file? One thing you are not doing is setting the layout parameters for your buttons correctly. If they are children of a `RelativeLayout`, you need to specify how they should be positioned. Otherwise they might be just one on top of the other.

Comment: I've shared it, and added making the layout parameters. Not that the buttons are showing up yet.

Comment: I don't see where you're adding anything to the `ScrollView`, did I miss it?